# NextJS 13 Dynamic routing not working on Google Cloud Run platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm encountering an issue with dynamic routing in my Next.js application when deploying it on the Google Cloud Run platform. The dynamic routing works fine locally, but when deployed on Google Cloud Run, the route parameters are not being passed correctly.

I have a page component called ListingPage that retrieves data based on the listingId parameter from the URL. Here's the code for the component:

```
import getCurrentUser from "@/app/actions/getCurrentUser";
import { getListingById } from "@/app/actions/listingsActions";
import ClientOnly from "@/app/components/ClientOnly";
import EmptyState from "@/app/components/EmptyState";
import ListingClient from "./ListingClient";
import getReservations from "@/app/actions/getReservations";

interface IParams {
  listingId?: string;
}

const ListingPage = async ({ params }: { params: IParams }) => {
  const listing = await getListingById(params.listingId as string);
  const reservations = await getReservations(params);
  const user = await getCurrentUser();

  if (!listing) {
    return (
      <ClientOnly>
        <EmptyState />
      </ClientOnly>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ClientOnly>
      <ListingClient
        listing={listing}
        reservations={reservations}
        currentUser={user}
      />
    </ClientOnly>
  );
};

export default ListingPage;
```

The issue is that when accessing the page on the Google Cloud Run platform, the params object is undefined, causing the API calls to fail.

I have verified that the URL pattern and parameter name match between my local environment and the deployed version on Google Cloud Run. The URL format is [http://example.com/listings/{listingId}](http://example.com/listings/%7BlistingId%7D) where {listingId} should be the actual ID.

I have also tried other approaches, such as using useRouter from next/router to access the query parameters, but it seems that useRouter is not available in server-side components.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with dynamic routing on the Google Cloud Run platform? How can I ensure that the params object is properly populated with the route parameters?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Cloud Run logs HTTP requests. Look in Cloud Run logging. Is the URL what you expect?

Comment: In my Cloud Run HTTP requests, I see that params print in console.log normally and everything works, however when being passed to functions they are undefined.